# Creation dynamic page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Suppose, I have a page and she has a button!
Question: can I create a dynamic page (like MainPage) when I click on the button?

Comment: Please mention what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = new ContentPage();
page.Title = "My New Page";
page.Content = // add a layout and content here

...

Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.